# How to handle a single loading indicator for the whole application using React and Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, antd

My web application sometimes need to polling back-end for fetching data. These actions usually take about 6 or 7 seconds. And during these polling, I want users are not allowed to interact on the UI.

What I have done is, in each component state, there are some flags such as `loading`, `success`, `error` for showing loading status on component level. But users still can interact with other components => this make handling edge cases are very difficult. So, I want when the app is in polling state, user cannot interact on the other component for a predictable and consistent flow.

What I expect is, a modal popup appears whenever there is a polling, then users only see that modal popup with some loading status and cannot interact on the UI.

Can you guys suggest me a direction for this? Using Redux (It's better if I can re-use modal pop-up from Antd https://ant.design/components/modal/#header).

Comment: It doesn't really matter what UI-library you use. You can open your modal in your parent components (the one containing Switch-Router (if you have any)) and block all other components from the top level.

Comment: What kind of answer you looking for? You just need to dispatch an action and show the modal overlay when needed

Comment: Also, this question is too broad. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

let me share my code

**route_reducer.js**

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  ....
  errorMessage: "",
  loading: false
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    ....
    case UPDATE_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        errorMessage: action.payload.error,
        loading: action.payload.loading
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**route_actions.js**

```
//update loading spinner and error message
export const updateErrorAndLoading = (error = "",loading = false) => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: UPDATE_ERROR, payload: { error, loading } });
};
```

**Home.js**

you should deal with some conditional rendering (in your App or something). if `this.props.loading` true then show spinner and don't show other components...etc.

```
import {  Spin } from "antd";

class Home extends Component {

render() {
//you can pass error message or check some conditions like 
//this.props.errorMessage.trim() === "" ?null: <div>your custom componet..etc, {this.props.errorMessage}</div>

 const spinner = this.props.loading ? (
      <Spin size="large" className="spinner" />
    ) : null;

 return (
   <>
    {/* spinner */}
    {spinner}
   </>


const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
     ...,
    errorMessage: state.route.errorMessage,
    loading: state.route.loading
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  actions
)(Home);
```

**App.css**
make class `.spinner` position `fixed` or `absolute` as per your need and give your own CSS attributes

```
/* spinner */
.spinner {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 10em;
    margin-left: 10px !important;
    margin-top: 10px !important;
    height: 50px;
    left: 1em;
    z-index: 200;
}
```

in your any component you can pass error message or loading state

```
showSpinner=()=>{
this.props.updateErrorAndLoading("some error occured", true);
}
closeSpinner=()=>{
this.props.updateErrorAndLoading(undefined, undefined);
}
```

[image: error message]

full page
[image]

let me know if you are able to implement this or not.